# Unable to use custom account adapter

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have the following in `adapter.py`:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class CustomAllauthAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    pass # keeping it trivial for debugging
```

At the very bottom of `settings.py`:

```
import django
django.setup() # complains about apps not being loaded yet without this...

from .adapter import CustomAllauthAdapter
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = CustomAllauthAdapter # this is the line that results in the error!
```

As soon as I submit the registration form for a new user, I get this error in the browser:

```
AssertionError at /api/v1/users/auth/register/
No exception message supplied
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\views.py", line 47, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\views.py", line 66, in create
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 220, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 419, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 478, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = validate_method(validated_value)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\serializers.py", line 209, in validate_email
    email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\adapter.py", line 535, in get_adapter
    return import_attribute(app_settings.ADAPTER)(request)
  File "C:\Dropbox\Parnasa\Web\drmeir\env\lib\site-packages\allauth\utils.py", line 153, in import_attribute
    assert isinstance(path, str)
```

If I do not set the `ACCOUNT_ADAPTER`, everything works well including registration and authentication. I need to use custom account adapter to customize email verification.

Why am I getting the error and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No need to import anything and no need for `django.setup()`. The configuration variable is a string!

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.adapter.CustomAllauthAdapter'
```